# STM32F103C8 - какое макс. время работы и как обезопасить от перегрева?

Tags: stm32, физика, электроника

Имеется STM32F103C8Tx и дисплей(5641AH10) (никаких резисторов, всё подклюено напрямую). Сделал часы. Всё работает, но вопрос: насколько долго можно оставлять их от питания через mini usb? Как обезопасить, что бы не сгорел ни дисплей, ни плата?

Схема: (у меня дисплей другой - 6 ножек, ибо на схеме двоеточие между цифрами, а у меня просто точка, но это не играет особой важности, ибо что тот, что тот - 7 сегментный, 4-х цифровой)

[image]

Comment: Без электросхемы и даташита на дисплей ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: @gbg добавил схему. Даташит на дисплей потерял, но там ничего важного не было, можно найти точно такой же 7-сегментный дисплей с 4 цифрами

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В теории, в режиме динамической индикации, это дело должно жить достаточно долго.

Однако, на практике, отечественные диоды, работающие на максимальной яркости, накроются за пару месяцев от перегрева.

Так что не занимайтесь кроиловым (которое ведет к попадалову) - добавьте резисторы.

Резистор имеет два основных параметра, о которых спрашивает продавец радиолавки - сопротивление (в Омах) и рассеиваемая мощность (в Ваттах).

Их можно вычислить, опираясь на школьный учебник физики:

Резисторы для светодиода считаются исходя из закона Ома для участка цепи. Для расчета нужно знать параметры светодиодов в индикаторе - максимальный ток и падение напряжения.

Типичные значения - 20 миллиампер и 1.5 вольта. Работать на максимальном токе нежелательно, поэтому берем 15 миллиампер.

При выборе тока для светодиодного дисплея следует также руководствоваться допустимым током через пин контроллера, допустимым суммарным током через пины контроллера, деленным на количество одновременно включенных сегментов (когда восьмерку включаете) и выбирать минимум из этих трех значений.

Напряжение питания у нас 5 вольт, на светодиоде падает 1.5, значит, резистору достанется 3.5 вольта. Ток через резистор равен току через светодиод (читать учебник физики, последовательное соединение), таким образом, его сопротивление равно R = U/I R = 3.5 / 0.015 = 233.(3) ома.

Резисторы на 233.(3) ома промышленность не выпускает, ближайший стандартный - 270 ом.

Тепловой расчет - на резисторе будет выделяться тепло. По закону Джоуля-Ленца, это будет P = I * U = 0.015 * 3.5 = 0.0525 Вт

Ближайший [стандартный промышленный резистор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9) имеет мощность рассеяния 0.125 Вт.

Подключать резисторы нужно на линии A0-A6.

Для случая других напряжений питания, например 3.3 Вольта, расчет нужно будет переделать!

Comment: Немного непонятно здесь - "Напряжение питания у нас 5 вольт, на светодиоде падает 1.5, значит, резистору достанется 3.5 вольта.", 5 вольт это, как пример, ток от пина платы к светодиоду? А 1.5 это берётся из даташита? И 20 миллиампер тоже с даташита? Для практики попытался расчитать резистор для TAR5503 - https://components101.com/7-segment-display-pinout-working-datasheet , там 30mA написано, это то?

Comment: Не путайте термины. Ток не может измеряться в вольтах. На бытовом уровне это допустимо, на инженерном - нет.
5 вольт - это примерное напряжение между пином и землей. В случае STM32, это будет скорее всего 3.3 вольта

1.5V берется из даташита, 20 ma - тоже из даташита 

В своем даташите, 30ma вы нашли верно.

Comment: Извиняюсь, но последний раз спрошу на всякий - вот нашёл даташит на свой дисплей - http://www.xlitx.com/Products/7-segment-led-dot-matrix/5641ah.html. Верно взял значения: U = 1,5  I = 0.010 (или брать который ниже - 30mA)?

Comment: Падение напряжения (Forward Voltage) у вас -  1.8V

А вот ток надо брать минимальный из трех - ток светодиода (Continuous Forward Current Per Dice) - (30 ma)  - ток через пин контроллера (смотреть даташит) и суммарный ток через пины контроллера (смотреть тот же даташит)

Comment: Получилось 60 Ом (U = 3.3 - 1.8 = 1.5    I = 0.025 (всё же взял 30mA, но немного понизил) ). Это где такой найти? SMD-шный что-ли

Comment: Ближайший стандартный резистор - 68 Ом. Я добавил в ответ ссылку на вики, где расписано, откуда берутся номиналы радиодеталей.
Вид корпуса резистора определяется не сопротивлением - вы можете найти подходящий резистор как в корпусе SMD, так и в корпусе для монтажа в отверстия

Comment: А вы учли ток, который может выдавать через свои ноги контроллер?